# clang++ can not locate c++ header and library

Tags: c++, macos, clang

My OS is OS X 10.10.2 and the default compiler for C is clang.
But this version of clang does not support ubsan (undefined sanitizer) which comes in the 3.4 release of clang. I also want to use KLEE to do some analysis. AFAIK KLEE works well with LLVM-<=3.4. I decided to install 
llvm-3.4 and clang-3.4 in my laptop.

After installing clang-3.4 in my system, I encountered a issue that the compiler can not locate the c++ header file. I installed clang-3.4 in /usr/local and I can find the c++ header file in /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.4. How can I add this directory to the search path of clang-3.4 and also the c++ library?

for the following demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hellow World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using command `clang++ test.cpp`, I got the error

```
test1.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Below is the version of clang I used

```
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

I used the following shell command to install llvm-3.4 and clang-3.4:

```
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/llvm-3.4.src.tar.gz \
     http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/clang-3.4.src.tar.gz \
     http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/clang-tools-extra-3.4.src.tar.gz \
     http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/compiler-rt-3.4.src.tar.gz
tar zxf llvm-3.4.src.tar.gz
tar zxf clang-3.4.src.tar.gz -C llvm-3.4/tools
mv llvm-3.4/tools/clang{-3.4,}
tar zxf clang-tools-extra-3.4.src.tar.gz -C llvm-3.4/tools/clang/tools
mv llvm-3.4/tools/clang/tools/{clang-tools-extra-3.4,extra}
tar zxf compiler-rt-3.4.src.tar.gz -C llvm-3.4/projects
mv llvm-3.4/projects/compiler-rt{-3.4,}

cd llvm-3.4
./configure --enable-cxx11  \
                      --enable-bindings=none --enable-shared \
                      --enable-debug-symbols --enable-optimized
make
make install
```

Now I have two versions of clang in my OS, one is the default one shipped with OSX located in /usr/bin and the other is clang-3.4 located in /usr/local/bin. The previous one can find the C++ header file while the latter can not.

Comment: You don't give enough details. Show a small source code. Show how you are compiling it (which compiler commands and options). Show the exact messages. How did you get or installed your compiler? So *edit your question* since it needs to be improved.

Comment: What is the program that requires specifically clang 3.4 ?

Comment: I need to use clang to compile the source program and then use KLEE to analyze the bit code file. KLEE works well with LLVM (version <=3.4) .  I also want to use ubsan (undefined behavior sanitizer) which comes in the 3.4 (or 3.3) release of clang.

Comment: UBSAN exists AFAIK in Clang 3.5 and I am guessing that a binary code anlalyzer does not care that much about the version of the compiler use to produce it (and more about the optimizations). But I am not using MacOSX but only Linux, so details are different.

Comment: And you should edit another time your question to tell about KLEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [user documentation of  `clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) notably the section on [command line options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options) ? BTW, [current](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) (march 2015) version of  `clang`  is [3.6](http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html)!

For C++ code you should use the `clang++`  command, not the `clang` command.

You might pass `-I`  and `-L`  options to `clang++`  but you might perhaps have misinstalled your `clang`  compiler.

You should be aware of the `-v` and `-H`  options of `clang` or `clang++` ; they could be useful, at least to understand more your issue.

---

#### addenda

BTW, a program reported to work with Clang 3.4 is extremely likely to work with a more modern version, like Clang 3.5 or 3.6

You probably have a `PATH` issue; you should have `configure` -d your Clang-3.4 & LLvm-3.4 programs with `--program-suffix=-my-3.4` (if you do that, repeat your entire compiler build and installation) and you probably should run `/usr/local/bin/clang++-my-3.4` ; maybe you also need some `--with-gcc-toolchain`  additional `configure` option.

I'm pretty sure that you should be able to try to compile or use your mysterious software requiring Clang-3.4 with a more modern version like 3.5 or 3.6 ; your MacOSX 10.10.2 is rumored to have a Clang-3.5 based system compiler, it very probably is able to compile and work with your mysterious software.